# Meaning of "doesn't go far enough" and "More than confidence."

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Context:

> The problem is that "confidence" doesn't go far enough. More than confidence, for people to invest in the world they have to trust in it — in the systems and people that make it work."

1. doesn't go far enough
2. More than confidence

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/lloyd-blankfein-wrong-about-markets-2016-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part:

> The problem is that "confidence" doesn't go far enough.

Means that "confidence" isn't enough for people to invest. It is thus logically followed by:

> More than confidence, for people to invest in the world they have to trust in it — in the systems and people that make it work."

Which means that, "for people to invest in the world", they need to have confidence, **but also** to trust in it.

Comment: I think your analysis is completely correct, but I would add that I think the "more than confidence" sentence is really ugly and badly written.  It starts out as a statement about a noun - "confidence" - but then turns into a statement with a completely different structure that doesn't really follow, grammatically.  For example, "More than confidence, trust is needed..." works, because there's a parallelism.  In the original sentence, the author is comparing "for people to invest" with "confidence", which is jarring.